# Capturar data do QDateEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Estou precisando pegar a data de um `QDateEdit`. Fiz o *designer* utilizando Qt Designer, em propriedades ativei `calendarPopup` e o `displayFormat` para `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Quero capturar essa data para inserir em uma consulta. Já tentei usar os seguintes códigos:

```
data = self.dlg.data.currentDate() # apresenta um erro 'QDateEdit' object has no attribute 'currentDate'
```

Já tentei outra forma:

```
data = self.dlg.data.date() # Até pego a data, mas no formato estranho veja: "PyQt4.QtCore.QDate(2016, 9, 14)"
```

Utilizei também:

```
data = self.dlg.data.currentSection() # traz um número 512, mas não no formato dd/MM/yyyy.
```

Qual a solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para retornar a data em *string* use o método [`qdate#toPyDate`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdate.html#toPyDate):

```
data = self.dlg.data.date().toPyDate()
```

Comment: Cara, passei um tempão olhando a documentação do QDateEdit e não vi isso e você em questão de minutos me respondeu.

Comment: Valeu mano. Obrigado!